# How to convert a QString to a point (x, y, z) easily?

Tags: qt, qstring

I have a struct point

```
struct Point
{
    double x;
    double y;
    double z;
}
```

And want to convert it to a QString "(value of x, value of y, value of z)" and convert it back? Any easy way? What I figured out for the forward conversion is

```
QString PointToString( const Point& pt )
{
     return QString("(%1, %2, %3)").arg(pt.x).arg(pt.y).arg(pt.z);
}
```

And I cannot figure out how to convert it back.

```
Point StringToPoint( const QString& s )
{
     // How?
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use regular expressions:

```
QString s = "(2, 5.3, 1e8)";
QRegExp regexp("\\(([^,]+), ([^,]+), ([^)]+)\\)");
if (regexp.exactMatch(s)) {
  double x = regexp.capturedTexts()[1].toDouble();
  double y = regexp.capturedTexts()[2].toDouble();
  double z = regexp.capturedTexts()[3].toDouble();
  qDebug() << x << y << z;
}
```

Output: `2 5.3 1e+08`

Be aware that `arg` can produce a number representation with comma separator (e.g. '3,14') on systems with certain locales. Parsing this representation would be problematic. So you should use `QLocale::c().toString(number)` to perform system independent conversion.

Comment: I am not familiar with regular expression. What is the regular expression for `QString ( double )` like `km (1000)'? Thanks a lot!

Comment: It would be something like `"km \\(([^)]+)\\)"`.